# How do I update an object in NSMutableArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I am trying to update an object in **NSMutableArray**.

```
Product *message = (Product*)[notification object];
Product *prod = nil;

for(int i = 0; i < ProductList.count; i++)
{
    prod = [ProductList objectAtIndex:i];
    if([message.ProductNumber isEqualToString:prod.ProductNumber])
    {
        prod.Status = @"NotAvaiable";
        prod.Quantity = 0;
        [ProductList removeObjectAtIndex:i];
        [ProductList insertObject:prod atIndex:i];
        break;
    }
}
```

Is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Remove lines:

```
[ProductList removeObjectAtIndex:i];
[ProductList insertObject:prod atIndex:i];
```

and that will be ok!

Comment: There is because [NSArray objectAtIndex:index] returns pointer to the object.

Comment: Using objectAtIndex to retrieve a value, modifying it, and then using replaceObjectAtIndex is better.

Answer (score 21):

For updating, use

`- (void)replaceObjectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index  withObject:(id)anObject`

But it is not needed in this case, since you are modifying the same object.

Answer (score 11):

You could start by using [fast enumeration](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocFastEnumeration.html), which is faster and easier to read. Also, you don't need to remove and insert the object, you can just edit it in line. Like this:

```
Product *message = (Product*)[notification object];

for(Product *prod in ProductList)
{
    if([message.ProductNumber isEqualToString:prod.ProductNumber])
    {
        prod.Status = @"NotAvailable";
        prod.Quantity = 0;
        break;
    }
}
```

(Is `ProductList` an object? If it is, it should start with a lowercase letter: `productList`. Capitalized names are for classes. Also, `Status` and `Quantity` are properties and should too start with a lowercase letter. I highly suggest you follow the [Cocoa naming conventions](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001281-BBCHBFAH).)

Answer (score 6):

Use `-insertObject:atIndex:` or `replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:`.

Answer (score 5):

There are two approaches

1. Create a new object and replace the old object with the new object

> ```
> for(int i = 0; i < ProductList.count; i++)         
>    {
>       prod = [ProductList objectAtIndex:i];
>       if([message.ProductNumber isEqualToString:prod.ProductNumber])
>        {
>            newObj = [[Product alloc] autorelease];
>            newObj.Status = @"NotAvaiable";
>            newObj.Quantity = 0;
>            [ProductList replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:newObj];
>            break;
>        } 
>
>      }
> ```

---

Update the existing object:

```
for(int i = 0; i < ProductList.count; i++)
    {
        prod = [ProductList objectAtIndex:i];
        if([message.ProductNumber isEqualToString:prod.ProductNumber])
        {
            prod.Status = @"NotAvaiable";
            prod.Quantity = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
```